# Clojure function in let binding

Tags: function, binding, clojure, let

If I have a function that evaluates to a function

```
(defn func1 [c1 c2]
  (fn [x1 x2]
    ...do some stuff with c1 c2 x1))
```

that I use elsewhere in a map or reduce, is it better to use inline

```
(defn func2 [x y z]
  (reduce (func1 x y) z (range 20)))
```

or to let bind it first

```
(defn func2 [x y z]
  (let [ffunc (func1 x y)]
    (reduce ffunc z (range 20))))
```

In the first case I would be worried that a new function over x and y is generated each step through the reduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The evaluation of the function call `(func1 x y)` is done once in each case.

The rule for evaluating a function call  in Clojure consists of evaluating all the expressions that are provided as its arguments and then invoking the function with those values.

If you define the following higher order function:

```
(defn plus []
  (println "calling plus")
  +)
```

And then call reduce in the following way:

```
(reduce (plus) [0 1 2 3])
```

A single `calling plus` is printed, showing the function `plus` is invoked only once.

The same thing happens when using the `let` form:

```
(let [f (plus)]
  (reduce f [0 1 2 3]))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I was looking for.  Never thought to test it with a side-effect.  Thanks.

Comment: Note also that instantiating functions is generally cheap anyway, so even if multiple functions were allocated it wouldn't be a big deal. Obviously you can construct functions which are expensive to build, but it's not like you're having to recompile the function each time (I mention this because newcomers to closures often thing they are compiled each time they are constructed).